# VSCode pylint not displaying relative import failures

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am running a Django application in VSCode, using pylint, and the relative imports errors are not displaying. They were before I installed a newer version of VSCode.

I have tried changing user settings and also workspace settings, but still can't get the errors to show.

User Settings

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "window.menuBarVisibility": "default",
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
    "update.enableWindowsBackgroundUpdates": false,
    "update.channel": "none",
    "php.validate.run": "onSave",
}
```

Workspace settings

```
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pep8Enabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"],
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/justin/anaconda3/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "/home/justin/anaconda3/bin/pylint"
}
```

At the top of one of my functions, a couple of different relative imports. Which one is right or wrong, VSCode should show me. Both imports are in the same project directory in Django, therefore import should be a single '.' I believe.

```
from .performance import get_perf_dates, get_perf_data
from ..models import DistributionList, Legend
```

Comment: This looks like more of a python question than a django question to me.

Comment: VS Code didn't change its handling of pylint in recent releases, so I'm wondering if you upgraded pylint and perhaps that changed things? And are you saying that pylint isn't complaining about the imports not working?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I also shared my workspace settings with another machine over Dropbox. If that may affect things.